# AIR/AS3: Upload portion of a File without creating a new new File chunk

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, air

I'm currently building an AIR file uploader designed to handle multiple and very large files. I've played around with different methods of breaking up file into chunks(100mb) and progressively uploading each so that I can guard agains a failed upload/disconnection etc.

I have managed to break up the file in smaller files which I then write to a scratch area on the disc however I'm finding that the actual process of writing the file is quite slow and chews up a lot of processing power. My UI basically grinds to a halt when its writing. not to mention that I'm effectively doubling the local disc space of every file.

The other method I used was to read into the original file in 100mb chunks and store that data in a byteArray which I can then upload as a POST data using the URLLoader class. Problem is that this way I cant keep track of the upload progress because the ProgressEvent.PROGRESS does not work properly for POST requests.

What I would like to know is if it's possible to read into the file in my 100mb chunks and upload that data without having to create a new file but still using the FileReference.upload() method in order to listen to all the available events that method gives me. Ie. create a File() that is made up of bytes 0 - 100mb of the original file, then call upload() on that new File.

I can post my code for both methods if that helps.

Cheers, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem, but we were solve it in another way, we decided to write an socket connector, which will connect to server (e.g. FTP/HTTP) and write down to socket this ByteArray, and we did it also in chunks around the same size, and the biggest file we had to upload was BlueRay movie around ~150GB.

So I hope you got some interesting ideas from my message, If you'd like it, I could share some piece of code for you.

Comment: Hmm that's a clever workaround because I can see that the Socket Class  dispatches a ProgressEvent. That would be great if you could share an example, Cheers

Comment: iam trying to achieve something very similar at the moment. could you post the example?